# installing Nagios 3.5.0 on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, nagios, installation

Hi I am getting the following errors when i run make all

```
/usr/bin/install: cannot stat `nagios': No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [install-basic] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/nagios/nagios/base'
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/nagios/nagios/base'
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I am following
http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nagios-3.4.4-on-centos-6.3
and also added the following

```
1) Create Account Information

Become the root user.

su -l

Create a new nagios user account and give it a password.

/usr/sbin/useradd -m nagios

passwd nagios

Create a new nagcmd group for allowing external commands to be submitted through the web interface. Add both the nagios user and the apache user to the group.

/usr/sbin/groupadd nagcmd

/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G nagcmd nagios

/usr/sbin/usermod -a -G nagcmd apache
```

before i ran the make all

Comment: You should add the Epel yum repo and install nagios like shown here: http://sharadchhetri.com/2012/08/05/installing-nagios-3-4-centos-6-3/

Answer (score 1):

Is this directory is present on your Nagios Server?

```
/root/nagios/nagios/base
```

Instead of the doc you are following I suggest follow Nagios Quick Start Guide for Fedora as CentOS is also RPM based

```
 http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/quickstart-fedora.html
```

Comment: yes, also I just uninstalled everything, and followed the steps on that URL it has not been designed for 3.5.0 it is for an older version on nagios.

Comment: is it throwing you any error? I believe it should work fine irrespective any version of Nagios.

Comment: yes that is also giving me the same errors

Comment: What error are you getting please provide some logs from your servers..